# How do I solve this exercise of double integral $\iint_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}dA$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have the double integral $\iint_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}dA$ where $D$ is the domain given by:

$D = \left \{ (x, y ) \in \mathbb R^{2} : x^{2}+y^{2} \le 2y\right \} $

I tried this in polar coordinates: $$\left ( r cos \Theta \right )^{2} + \left ( r sin \Theta - 1 \right )^{2} = 1 $$

$$r = 2sin\Theta $$ $$\int_{-\Pi /4}^{\Pi /4}\int_{0}^{2sin\Theta } \frac{1}{r} rdrd\Theta$$

Am I the right way? How to resolve then?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean: $D = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 +y^2 \leq 2y \} $? See e.g. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please also insert in the questions additional informations. Best, show the own tries, so that potential answerers can focus on the soft spot. Informations on level, source, methods tried or from the context where the problem occured, etc. are always welcome. It is the way it works. (And also prohibits the downvotes.)

Comment: I don't understand how you get that integral at all.  To begin with, why is $(r\cos\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta-1)^2   = r$?  Can't you just make the substitution $u=y-1$ in the integral so you can integrate over $x^2+u^2\leq1$?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong in the integral, I forgot the square. I updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a diagram: the correct range for $\theta$ is from $\pi/4$ to $3\pi/4$, giving$$\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}drd\theta=\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}2\sin\theta d\theta=[-2\cos\theta]_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}=2\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: It may be that range for θ is [0, $\pi$] ? and the result is 4? I am confused about that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @grf2018 Find the lines through the origin that are tangents to this circle.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+y^2\le 2y$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-2y\le 0$$
$$x^2+(y-1)^2-1\le 0$$
$$x^2+(y-1)^2\le 1$$
so this is the circular region you are integrating over

Comment: I tried this in polar coordinates:

\left ( r cos \Theta  \right )^{2} + \left ( r sin \Theta - 1 \right )^{2} = 1

r = 2sin\Theta

\int_{-\Pi /4}^{\Pi /4}\int_{0}^{2sin\Theta } \frac{1}{r} rdrd\Theta

Comment: @grf2018 You need to put `$` signs around MathJax commands in order for them to be effective.  Also, clarifications like this should go in the body of the question, not the comments, so that they can be seen by people browsing the questions.  I'm editing your question to add the comment.